# How can I set the database time zone for a query?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am working on two systems which access the same PostgreSQL database:

- a Windows exe app, and
- a Code Igniter PHP web app

Both systems output basically the same stuff.

One issue I'm having currently is that I need to produce a report of data which is specific to a "location" which is in a different time zone to the server. All date/time data for readings, etc are stored in `TIMESTAMPTZ` format.

Both systems first set the database time zone calling a function which does...

```
EXECUTE 'SET TIME ZONE ''' || (
        SELECT time_zone_name
            FROM  location
            WHERE location_code = in_location_code) || '''';
```

They then call the same stored procedure to construct the XML to pass through the same XSL transform to end up as an HTML/PDF report.

The Windows exe creates the report with the correct time-adjusted **"Report Generated at..."** date in the heading and all relevant dates/times in the report are correctly offset by the time zone difference.

But the PHP app's not correctly setting the heading date/time, and all the internal dates throughout the report show the server time zone time, not the offset for the remote location.

I can see the start and end date getting passed from the PHP app to the d/b query with the dates showing the correct date/time including the TZ offset but for all the world, it seems the d/b is ignoring the previous `SET TIME ZONE` call.

Comment: Are these reports both running on the same system? Do you know where the binary app is getting its timestamp for the report header? -PHP will use the system time by default, unless the header value is actually coming from the DBMS as part of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue myself in the end.

The PHP app was setting the time zone correctly, but then there were multiple subsequent calls setting the `search_path` and I think it was this which reset the time zone back to server time.

In the end, I added a line into the various report stored procedures to set the time zone in there, making sure any `TIMESTAMPTZ` variable assignments were made after this.

It didn't affect the PC app but fixed the PHP app.